# How to fly in minecraft

Tags: mods, minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I see a lot of videos where peoples building big building and villages in a time lapse. When I see them, they are flying so they can reach the spot faster. How they do that, is it a Bukkit mod ?

Is it hard to configure the game so I can do the same thing in Multiplayer ? Or my Bukkit server?

Comment: Throw yourself at the ground and miss.

Comment: @Sam He's not asking how to enter orbit, he's asking how to *fly*.

Comment: On several Bukkit and often Tekkit servers there are commands like fly these are often acquired by downloading Bukkit mods or things like single player commands, often in time lapses people use creative mode as it is all round easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fairly easy.

There are a number of client-side flymods out there, the most popular being [Zombe's Modpack](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/91055-v173-zombes-modpack-26-mods-v431-upd-28jul/). Just follow the included installation instructions and press `F` to toggle flying.

As of Beta 1.5, flying is (per default) disabled on vanilla servers. You can reenable it by setting [`allow-flight=true`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties#allow-flight) in `server.properties`. If you want to allow only certain groups to be able to fly on your server, I highly recommend getting Bukkit plus an anti-cheat plugin like [NoCheat](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/sec-nocheat-v1-11b-detect-and-fight-the-exploitation-of-various-flaws-bugs-in-mc-1000.4523/).

Comment: Flight can now be disabled in vanilla servers via the [`allow-flight` setting](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Server.properties#allow-flight) — and is disabled by default.

Comment: Seems to be only for Windows or Mac users... any Linux one ?

Comment: @Ben Blank You are correct, I totally forgot about allow-flight, I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Warface The Mod should also work fine on Linux, Minecrafts files are located in `~/.minecraft`.

Answer (score 11):

Creative mode in 1.8 has inbuilt support for flying. It is available by double tapping space.

Answer (score 1):

**Reedit:** Using these instructions, you can switch a survival map to creative:

1. Download NBTedit from [here](http://copy.mcft.net/mc/NBTedit/NBTedit.zip)
2. Unzip the ZIP file
3. Run NBTedit
4. Click File -> Open
5. Navigate to your save folder
6. Open `level.dat`
7. Switch `gamemode` to `1`
8. Save and exit.

In multiplayer, ops can type `/gamemode [playername] [1 for creative, 0 for survival]`

**Edit:** This is wrong! There is a /fly command you can use! same controls

If you use "Single Player Commands" you can:

1. press "T" to open the Console
2. Use the command "/noclip" to allow you to fly around, however you can also "Fly" through blocks,.

Controls for /noclip flying:

WSAD: Move like normal
Shift: Go down
SPACE: Go up.

This isn't really "flying" in the sense that the Original-Poster meant but you are flying!

**Edit:** This is for Single-Player, not Multiplayer. Hopefully this will help someone who wants to fly in single-player but I don't think it works on multiplayer.

Comment: Upvoted for single player answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

The [WorldEdit](http://wiki.bukkit.org/WorldEdit_(Plugin)) plug-in has a feature where if you use the command /jumpto to move to the first available space above a block that you are looking at. This can also be bound to items (usually compasses) for easy access, it also has other ways of getting around such as /ascend and /descend.

Comment: That's not flying, it's teleporting...

Comment: You did say you wished to do it "to reach the spot faster" so this furfills the same purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Download plugin **Essentials**, then type **/fly** in chat.